# process descriptor initialization

Tags: linux, process, initialization, file-descriptor

In linux when a process starts, how is it's process descriptor filled? I would like to know where this is actually done. Which part of the code does the initialization (initialization of priority and it's schedule class and all). File name and the line number where it actually happens would help me.

How is prio, ststic_prio and normal_prio variables in sched.h are initialized? And exactly which part of the kernel code does this initialization??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your definition of "start"? For *fork*, see `kernel/fork.c:copy_process` in the kernel source, for *exec*, see `fs/exec.c:do_execve`.

Comment: As soon as i double click to start a process it's priority, scheduling class and some other things are initialized. I would like to know which part of the code in kernel does this initialization..

Answer (score -1):

Process descriptors are found in `init-scripts`

its found in the location `/etc/init.d`

you can go through the code, which contains methods for starting/stopping of the service, and description it shows while starting and stopping them.